# Reactjs:Objects are not valid as a React child - DotsMobileStepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am writing a React website and get following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes, displayName, handleNext, handleBack, activeStep, Naked, options, useStyles}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in Unknown (at EmergencyDetails/index.js:109) in SOS (created by Context.Consumer) in withRouter(SOS) (created by Context.Consumer) in Route (at App.js:34) in Router (created by BrowserRouter) in BrowserRouter (at App.js:32) in App (at withRoot.js:12) in ThemeProvider (at withRoot.js:9) in WithRoot (at src/index.js:7)
▶ 28 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | 
   9 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  10 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:149
  146 |         );
  147 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  148 |     }
> 149 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  150 | };
  151 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  152 |     return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5393:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | return result;
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/Repository/mpd-airbus-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:57
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

This is my SOS/index.js file, in there I render the DotsMobileStepper and pass handleNext and handleBack.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Header } from '../Layout';
import FormPersonType from './FormPersonType';
import FormEmergencyType from './FormEmergencyType';
import Textbox from './Textbox';
import AppContext from '../utils/AppContext';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';
import DotsMobileStepper from './DotsMobileStepper';

class SOS extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      componentType: 'type_of_emergency', //type_of_person //texbox
      ambulance: false,
      fire_service: false,
      police: false,
      car_service: false,
      meAffected: false,
      anotherPerson: false
    };

    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
    this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);
    this.handleEmergencyType = this.handleEmergencyType.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  showSettings(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleNext(e) {
    if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_emergency') {
      this.setState({ componentType: 'type_of_person' });
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_person')
      this.setState({ componentType: 'textbox' });
    else if (this.state.componentType === 'textbox')
      this.props.history.push('/transmitted_data');
  }

  handleBack(e) {
    if (this.state.componentType === 'textbox') {
      this.setState({ componentType: 'type_of_person' });
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_person') {
      this.setState({ componentType: 'type_of_emergency' });
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_emergency')
      this.props.history.push('/emergency_sent');
  }

  handleEmergencyType(new_emergency_state) {
    console.log(new_emergency_state);
    this.setState(new_emergency_state);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    console.log('in OnSubmit');
    axios
      .post(CONST.URL + 'emergency/create', {
        id: 1,
        data: this.state
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let component;

    if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_emergency') {
      component = (
        <FormEmergencyType
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          handleEmergencyType={this.handleEmergencyType}
          emergencyTypes={this.state}
          timerStart={this.timerStart}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_person') {
      component = (
        <FormPersonType
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          personTypes={this.state}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'textbox') {
      component = <Textbox handleFinished={this.handleFinished} />;
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header title="Specify Details" />
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
          {component}
        </Container>

        <DotsMobileStepper
          handleNext={this.handleNext}
          handleBack={this.handleBack}
          activeStep={this.state.onBoardingProgress}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(SOS);
```

I used the DotsMobileStepper defined in the materialUi, however I rewrote it as a class-Component because with the functional component the this.props.handle next was not working which I need because this is handled in the SOS/index.js file.

> DotsMobileStepper.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 400,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

class DotsMobileStepper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
  }
  // const classes = useStyles();
  render() {
    var theme = useTheme();
    const [activeStep] = React.useState(0);
    return (
      <MobileStepper
        variant="dots"
        steps={6}
        position="static"
        //activeStep={this.props.activeStep}
        activeStep={activeStep}
        className={this.classes.root}
        nextButton={
          <Button
            size="small"
            // onClick={this.props.handleNext.map(this.bind(this))} //this.props.buildings.map(this.renderBuildings.bind(this)
            disabled={activeStep === 3}
          >
            Next
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            )}
          </Button>
        }
        backButton={
          <Button
            size="small"
            onClick={this.props.handleNext.map(this.bind(this))}
            disabled={activeStep === 0}
          >
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            )}
            Back
          </Button>
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(DotsMobileStepper);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you are, somewhere in that code, returning a Javascript object inside the render functions.

My advice? Delete piece by piece util you find where is the culprit.

Comment: Could you be a bit more concrete? I cannot simply remove var theme and const[activeStep] because otherwise I need to rewrite the whole class but otherwise in return there should only be this one MobileStepper JSX element. So do you know what might be the problem or where I could define the theme and activeStep?

Comment: @pythonlearner then you know the problem comes from these two?